# What is the terminology for integers with the same oddness or evenness?

Tags: terminology, number-theory

If two integers are either both negative or both positive, we can say they have the same sign.

How about two integers that are either both odd or both even? Is there any term for them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)

Comment: You can also say they are congruent mod 2.

Comment: As @TomKern says: they have the *same parity*.  If one is odd and the other even, then they have *opposite parity*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expanding on a comment by @TomKern: The word you're looking for is **parity**.

You can see it in most standard English dictionaries, such as [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parity), here:

> 4 a: the property of an integer with respect to being odd or even
>
> ```
> 3 and 7 have the same parity
> ```
>
> b(1): the state of being odd or even used as the basis of a method of
> detecting errors in binary-coded data (see binary entry 2 sense 5)
>
> b(2): parity bit

And here's the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_(mathematics)) article on the subject.

> In mathematics, **parity** is the property of an integer of whether it
> is **even** or **odd**.

And here's the equivalent question at [Stack Exchange: English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/434962/word-that-means-the-classification-of-a-number-as-even-or-odd).